# Undeliverable email warning not forwarded from Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

*I have a Google Mail account which should forward all emails to my main email account.*

It works in 99% of cases with my current filters:

```
Matches: is:spam Do this: Never send it to Spam
Matches: from:(*) Do this: Skip Inbox, Mark as read, Apply label "MyArchive", 
                           Forward to mymainemail@email.com
```

But if I send an email that is undeliverable for some reason, I get an email in my *gmail inbox that does not get forwarded*:

```
Undeliverable: Subject-of-undeliverable-email
```

And because I use my main email account not the forwarding Gmail interface then I have no idea my email was not delivered.

#### Headers / Show Original

```
From: "System Administrator"
Sender: "System Administrator"
To: xxx
Subject: Undeliverable: yyy
Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 15:08:44 +0100
Message-ID: <asdf$@Domain>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef;
name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="winmail.dat"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: erger
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: egererg
X-OlkEid: asdfasd..........
```

---

How can I make all my emails to be forwarded, including the undeliverable notices?

Comment: You have to verify that the notice the email was undeliverable is actually sent from the email account, if it is anything like my domain email, its not the same.

Comment: @Ramhound i have edited the question to include the email headers

Answer (score 1):

From: [Automatically forward emails to another account - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en)

## Forward all new emails

1. Open the Gmail account that you want to forward from.
2. Click the gear in the top right.
3. Select Settings.
4. Select the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
   (Forwarding, POP & IMAP tab) (insert image here)
5. Click Add a forwarding address in the “Forwarding” section.
6. Enter the email address you want to forward to.
7. For your security, we'll send a verification email to that address. Open your other email account and find the confirmation message from the Gmail team. If you’re having trouble finding it, check your Spam folder.
8. Click the verification link in that email.
9. Back in your Gmail account, reload the page in your web browser - look for the reload icon Reload.
10. On the same Forwarding and POP/IMAP page in Settings, check that Forward a copy of incoming mail is selected and your email address is in the drop-down menu.
11. In the second drop-down menu, choose what you want Gmail to do with your messages after they’re forwarded, such as keep Gmail’s copy in the Inbox (recommended) or archive Gmail’s copy.
12. Click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.